# Unable to run cron job in kubernets

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

I have this cron job running on kubernetes:

```
#  cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: loadjob
spec:
  schedule: "05 10 31 Mar *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata: # Dictionary
          name: apiaplication
          labels: # Dictionary
            product_id: myprod
          annotations:
            vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-role: #{KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}#
            prometheus.io/path: /metrics
            prometheus.io/port: "80"
            prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: al-onetimejob
              image: #{TIMELOAD_IMAGE_TAG}#
              imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: OnFailure    
            
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: secret
```

In the above cron expression I have set it to today morning 10.05AM using cron syntax schedule: `05 10 31 Mar *` - but unfortunately when I checked after 10.05 my job (pod) was not running.

So I found it's not running as expected at 10.05 using the above expression. Can someone please help me to write the correct cron syntax? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the timezone of the master plane ? When you run date command does the time is aligned with yours ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron looks good but checks **timezone** of your Kubernetes cluster. **K8s cluster** might be following the **UTC** timezone and hope you are counting the same in **local** **timezone**.

This cron should work : `05 10 31 Mar *` but based on the cluster's **date** setup.

Comment: Yes that is the root cause. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the work `5 10 31 MAR FRI`.

I can recommend using website like [this](https://crontab.guru) to compose your `cron` schedules.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **timezone** in your cluster first, by executing the **date** command because most of the time zones will be in **UTC**. Use **date** command like follows

```
$ date
Fri Mar 31 07:21:47 UTC 2023
```

Now set the schedule time in the **cronjob** based on your timezone. For your requirement `5 10 31 MAR *` should work. Use this [crontab](https://crontab.guru/#5_10_31_MAR_*) site for formulating the time based on the syntax.